# IIS way to control remote port openings

Tags: iis, firewall, port

After my browser connects to a server page, a numerous **backwards connections**  from server to browser are opened. Assuming I am the admin, is there any way to control the remote ports range from server side?

[image: screenshot of opened connections to my browser, taken at server]

*my browser (remote) loading webpage at HTTPS:8834 server port*

I am interested in controlling this range in IIS, but have been unable to find anything for Apache either, so maybe this is more general question.

Comment: Why do you not start by finding out that port 8834 is not exactly http - that must be some plug in. This is not usual behavior for a web browser.

Comment: oh yeah you are right! i will use better image next time and now change the description

Comment: Anyhow, this is totally unrelated to IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be controlled as far as I know.  First time i've seen this type of question.  There is a range of ports Windows uses for dynamic allocation, which is the range you are seeing.  You can control dynamic ports but it requires having control of both the client and server to limit the number of dynamic ports.  For an internet facing site, this is not fesible.

Answer (score 0):

as to my own research, remote port openings are decisions of remote client's (internet visitor's) machine, and it makes such decisions BEFORE it is connected to local server port. So after that it may only be possible to tell the client somehow to change the port, but such request is not a part of HTTP or TCP/IP protocol anyway either.